# Can't comment my own question

Tags: support, comments, reputation

I learned a lot while reading Stack Exchange. Two days ago, I asked my first question and I received an excellent answer from the user Alenanno.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to comment my OWN question.
Every time I tried it, a message appeared saying I must at least have 50 repuations.
Does anybody know why?

Greets

Comment: I found the reason: I ask the question before registration. Is it possible to merge the two profiles?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/merge-user-accounts may help. I think there is a part about this point in help center but cannot remember where

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/contact and pick the appropriate option

Comment: I flagged the question to attrack the moderator's attention. I asked the first question without registration/as a guest. That's why the form in the link which Joseph Wright has posted said the account (http://stackexchange.com/users/7913841/mellon?tab=accounts) is invalid. Hope the mods are able to manage it. Sorry for the circumstances!